# Select and delete text in Cmder

Tags: cmder

I'd like to select the text and delete.

The behaviour of the Cmder is a little bit confusing.
If I select text leftward(e.g Shift+Left arrow, Shift+Home), I can delete the selected text, But when I select text using rightward(Shift+Right arrow, Shift+End), I can't delete.

Is this by design? or am I missing something?

Below is the description of those hotkeys

1. Shift+Left

Start text selection, ignored in Far, may be disabled on ‘Mark & Paste’ and ‘App distinct’ pages: Select(0,-1)

2. Shift + Right

Start text selection, ignored in Far, may be disabled on ‘Mark & Paste’ and ‘App distinct’ pages: Select(0,1)

Answer (score 2):

There is a checkbox in Settings -> Mark/Copy -> Start selection with Shift+Arrow which you must set. Without it, it won't work.